# Псевдоним функции php

Tags: php

У класса `Foo` есть статический метод `Test($a, $b)`, как можно создать псевдоним этого метода, чтобы можно было таким образом обращаться:

```
Foo::Test($a, $b); //Обычный вызов метода
```

Чтобы каждый раз не писать `Foo::Test`, хотелось создать свой псевдоним (в С++ можно было бы создать функцию ссылку на другую функцию)

Только это пришло в голову:

```
function T($a, $b){
   Foo::Test($a, $b);
}

T($a, $b); // короткий псевдоним
```

Существуют другие способы?

**И еще вопрос:**

Можно как-то этот класс подключить в файл, чтобы методы использовать как функции пространства имен. Т.е. при вызове статических методов, не надо было бы писать `Foo::test()`, а просто при вызове `Test`, метод был вызван из класса

Comment: Создать псевдоним можно так: `$callback = array('Foo', 'Test'); $callback($a, $b);`

Comment: А я и не знал что байты подорожали. Тоже начну экономить. Зачем создавать нечетаемый код?

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, для чего вам это понадобилось, видимо причина очень веская, но, имхо - это называется "экономия на спичках"

По второму вопросу. Нет.

По первому вопросу, вариантов три с половиной:

1. Вы его сами предложили, посему останавливаться на нем не будем.
2. Можно сделать как предложил ВОРОН

   ```
   $callback = array('Foo', 'Test'); 
   $callback("aa","bb");
   ```
3. для PHP 7

   ```
   $a="Foo::Test";
   $a("aaaaa","bbb");
   ```
4. (половинка) Если такая функция одна и не статическая, то можно использовать "магический метод" [__invoke](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke)

   ```
   class Foo{
       function __invoke($a, $b){
           echo $a, $b;
       }
   }

   $foo = new Foo();
   $foo($a, $b);
   ```

**UPD**

Конечно есть еще варианты с call_user_func, Reflection и т.д., но они всяко будут длиннее обычного статического вызова.